# What is the source column of each column in view

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, view, metadata, database-metadata

How can I know for each column in view, or procedure the source column
For example,
I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Address](
    [iAddressId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [nvStreet] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [iHouseNum] [int] NULL,
    [nvEnterance] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [iFloor] [int] NULL,
    [nvNeighberwood] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [nvCity] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [nvNote] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Address] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [iAddressId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And this view:

```
CREATE VIEW ViewALIAS
AS
SELECT a.nvStreet myStreet,a.nvCity manyStreeats FROM tbl_Address a
```

The required answer:

```
nameObject | nameColumn | SourceObject | SourceColumn  
----------------------------------------------------- 
tbl_Address| nvStreet   | ViewALIAS    | myStreet  
tbl_Address| nvCity     | ViewALIAS    | manyStreeats
```

I know how to make the columns: `nameObject`,  `nameColumn`, `SourceObject` 
or the table: `nameObject`, `SourceObject`, `SourceColumn`
But I do not know how to match x and t

Comment: One would have to parse the system table source for the view to obtain that data.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I make a plugin

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can't get exactly what you want (see explanation below) but you can get an approximation, first you can get all the columns of the view using:

```
select name, column_id from sys.columns where object_id=object_id('ViewALIAS')
```

and then you can get the columns referenced by the view using [column dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552358/sql-server-column-dependencies-without-deprecated-sys-view/46676111#46676111), note that this include all the columns used in any part of the query, not only columns in the select list (for example it would list a column used in a `WHERE` condition):

```
select dependencies.referenced_entity_name as referenced_name,
  entities.referenced_minor_id as column_id, entities.referenced_minor_name as column_name
from sys.sql_expression_dependencies as dependencies
join sys.objects as objects on object_id=referencing_id
join sys.schemas as schemas on schemas.schema_id=objects.schema_id
cross apply sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(schemas.name+'.'+objects.name,'OBJECT') as entities
where entities.referenced_entity_name=dependencies.referenced_entity_name
  and (is_schema_bound_reference=0 or entities.referenced_minor_id=dependencies.referenced_minor_id)
  and entities.referenced_minor_id!=0
  and referencing_id=object_id('ViewALIAS')
```

You can't link the two results because as far as I know there is no way in SQL Server of getting the relation between view columns and referenced columns in the [object catalog views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/object-catalog-views-transact-sql), I don't know the exact reason but I'm quite sure that the primary cause is that a view column could be almost anything, so it's not always possible match it to a table column, a few examples:

```
CREATE VIEW ExampleView AS
SELECT ID, -- table column
  (Value1+Value2)*Value3 as Total, -- multiple columns
  12345 as Value, -- literal value
  getdate() as CurrentDate, -- scalar function
  dbo.fnMyFunction(Value1,Value2) as ScalarColumn, -- scalar function with parameters
  TableFunctionColumn, -- column from a table function (which can be almost anything)
  CASE WHEN Value1<10000 THEN Value2
    WHEN Value1>20000 THEN Value3
    ELSE Value2+Value3 END AS CaseColumn, -- different columns based on another value
  (SELECT SUM(OtherValue) FROM OtherTable
    WHERE OtherID=ID GROUP BY OtherValue) AS SubqueryColumn -- subquery result
FROM ExampleTable
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnTableFunction(ID)
```

I think the `CASE` column is the most representative example because the table columns used by the view column depends on the value of *another* column which is not used directly for the column value.